# Total number of possible ways to repair N damaged components with M number of crews

Tags: combinatorics

Assuming there are *"N"* damaged components in a electric power network after an earthquake, and there are *"M"* number of crews out there that can work on the damaged components, and assuming that each crew can work on *"P"* number of damaged components simultaneously, what is the total number of possible resource allocation/restorations?

I believe there are `N!` ways of going through the damaged components like one-by-one (*"M"* = *"P"* = 1), and I suppose (I am not sure) that the total number of ways for allocating/distributing *"M"* crew between the *"N"* damaged components can be calculated as `N!/M!(N-M)!` (if this is true, I would aprreciate if you could explain why as I have zero experience in this area), but not only I am not sure about this but also I do not know how to include *"P"* in the solution!

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE ! When asking a question, you should us your work, what you have already done to answer it and where you have found a difficulty. It is advised to read the help topic ["How to ask"](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Tom-Tom Thank you for your comment .. I am going to modify my question right now :)

Comment: Do you always have $N=MP$?  If not, you either can't keep the crews busy or you will have some items unfixed after the first round.  The answer won't be nearly as neat as if $N=MP$  When you assign $P$ items to a crew, does it matter what order you assign them in?  It sounds like not.  In that case the number of ways to assign the first crew is $N \choose P$  Are the crews interchangeable?  Is assigning items $1,2,3$ to the first crew and $4,5,6$ to the second the same as assigning $4,5,6$ to the first and $1,2,3$ to the second?

Comment: In your example with $N=1500, M=200, P=3$ you fix $600$ things per round.  What happens after two rounds, when you don't have enough components for all the crews?

Comment: @RossMillikan Like in this example, in the last round just half of the crew will be working .. like the rest go home cuz they do not have any tasks to do anymore!

Comment: @RossMillikan But here is the challenge … what if the repair time is not the same for all components? In this case, at the end of the recovery process some crew might have only worked on 10-15 components, but some crews might have worked on let's say 40-50 components basically because those components  had minor damage and were easier/faster to repair. Do you think if this problem is solvable too (assuming that we know the repair time for each damaged component!)?

Comment: It is certainly solvable, but the solution will have many bits and pieces.  As the problem becomes less symmetric the answer quickly becomes a mess.  In that case finding the number of possible assignments becomes uninteresting.  People change their focus to finding the most efficient way of making the assignments.  You either need to integrate travel time between the components or just try to make the last repair happen as early as possible.

Comment: @RossMillikan could not expect a better answer! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absent better definition of the question, I will assume

1. $N=kMP$, so there are $k$ rounds of assigning repairs to each crew.  Each crew gets a full list of assignments each time
2. The crews are interchangeable, so assigning $1,2,3$ to the first crew and $4,5,6$ to the second is the same as assigning $4,5,6$ to the first and $1,2,3$ to the second
3. It matters which round a particular item is repaired

We can line up the $N$ items to repair in $N!$ ways, then break them into blocks of $P$ for assignment to crews.  The first $M$ blocks are repaired in the first round, the next $M$ in the second, and so on up to round $k$.  We ask how many different orders of the items result in the same assignment.  Each block can be reordered in $P!$ different ways so we divide by $(P!)^{\frac NP}$  The $M$ blocks in a round can be rearranged among the crews in $M!$ ways so we divide by $(M!)^k$  This gives 
$$\frac {N!}{(P!)^{\frac NP}(M!)^k}$$
different assignments.